# I am new to programming and I keep receiving an error message I don't know how to resolve

Tags: java, jgrasp

I am writing a program that receives a temperature input from the user and converts it to either Celcius or Fahrenheit but I keep receiving the error: cannot find the symbol.

I already tried changing some variable names and i've double-checked to see if it makes sense but since im new to programming I'm not really sure if I am looking at it the right way.

```java
import javax.swing.*;



public class Lab_two {




   public static void main (String[] args) {

   Object[] options = {"Celsius",         
                       "Fahrenheit",
                       "Cancel"};

      String initialInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the desired temperature to convert: ");       
      System.out.println(initialInput); 

      double numToConvert = Double.parseDouble(initialInput);

      int optionDialog = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Would you like to convert" + numToConvert + "to Celsius or Fahrenheit?",         
                                                         "Temperature Conversions", 0, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,null,
                                                          options, options[2]);
      boolean lop = true;           
      while(lop) {                                                               
         switch (optionDialog) {                                                                           
            case 0: CtoF(numToConvert);
                    System.out.println(tempC);  
               break;                              
            case 1: FtoC(numToConvert);
                    System.out.println(tempF);
               break;   
            case 2: System.out.println("Program canceled");
               lop = false;                
            default: System.out.println("canceled = reset");                           
         }
      }
   }

   public static double FtoC(double tempF) {

      double tempC = 5./9. * (tempF - 32);


      return tempC;
   }

   public static double CtoF(double tempC) {
      double tempF = 1.8 * tempC + 32;

      return tempF;
   }

}
```

If the user enters 77 and selects the Fahrenheit conversion then I would expect the output to be 25

instead, the console displays:

> ```
> Lab_two.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
>                     System.out.println(tempC);  
>                                        ^
>   symbol:   variable tempC
>   location: class Lab_two
> Lab_two.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
>                     System.out.println(tempF);
>                                        ^
> ```

Comment: You're going to need to learn about variable scope. If I were you, I wouldn't be trying to do full UI projects before you have a grasp of the basics of the language (no offence). UI code just complicates everything.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope

Comment: Downvote for stupid title. The title should express the actual problem, not your personal circumstances. People scan titles for questions they can answer, and this one won't entice anybody,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the scope of your local variables in the CtoF and FtoC methods.  'tempC' and 'tempF' are only available within the scope of those methods.  You need to assign the return value of the method call to a variable in the same scope as your print, or just use the method call directly in the arguments to print:

```
        case 0: 
            System.out.println(CtoF(numToConvert));  
            break;                              
        case 1: {
            double tmpC = FtoC(numToConvert);
            System.out.println(tmpC);
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `tempC` and `tempF` are defined locally in your `FtoC` and `CtoF` methods. They therefore cannot be referred to from the `main` method. To fix, assign result of `FtoC` and `CtoF` to appropriate variables inside the main method, e.g:

```
case 0:
  double tempC = CtoF(numToConvert);
  System.out.println(tempC);
  break;
case 1:
  double tempF = FtoC(numToConvert);
  System.out.println(tempF);
  break;
```

**Bonus:**

The "cannot find symbol" errors generally occur when you try to reference an undeclared variable in your code. Your code is basically referring to something that the compiler doesn't understand.

When your code is compiled, the compiler needs to work out what each and every identifier in your code means. As the compiler is going through the code it will find something and know what to do with it or not. Your cannot find symbol error relates to the identifiers and means that Java cannot figure out what the "symbol" means.